# Selecionar apenas um item

Tags: php, html

Eis o código:

```
<?php while($ver=mysql_fetch_row($busca)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" value="<?php echo "$var[0]"; ?>"></td><td><?php echo "$ver[0]"; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo "$ver[1]"; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo "$ver[2]"; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo "$ver[3]"; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo "$ver[4]"; ?></td>
    </tr>                  
<?php } ?>
```

E aqui só um deve ser selecionado, mas não é oque está ocorrendo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Falta elemento de "name" dentro do input radio para que só seja possível selecionar um.

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="group1" />
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
  <td>Col 4</td>
  <td>Col 5</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="group1" />
  </td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Col 2.2</td>
  <td>Col 3.2</td>
  <td>Col 4.2</td>
  <td>Col 5.2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="group1" />
  </td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>Col 2.3</td>
  <td>Col 3.3</td>
  <td>Col 4.3</td>
  <td>Col 5.3</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar como o seu primeiro campo ID, ou seja utilizando `$ver[1]` e utilize o atributo name.

```
<input type="radio" value="<?php echo "$ver[0]"; ?>" name="selecionado" />
```

Comment: O campo id é o $ver[0]

Comment: Legal, @EduardoBalestrin editado